# microsoft outlook 2007 has stopped working

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007

Outlook stops working when connected to internet, this started with a mail, when the mail is read :

this message appears " microsoft outlook has stopped working a problem caused program to stop working, close the program "

then when again i opened outlook, this time three mail in inbox from same sender , if you delete those mails, then after sometime again it comes and again outlook stops working , i am unable to read any mails.

This Video explains exactly what is happening:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ez5LWKTp9kY

I have tried Outlook in safe mode, and tried unchecking compatibility issues, disabled the ad-dins. But still same message appears, if its virus causing the problem then is there any way to scan for viruses in outlook? have you come across this message before ?

Thank You.

Comment: Adding a video showing the problem was a nice touch. Hopefully someone here will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you've already tried to run Outlook in a safe mode, it is possible that your PST file is corrupted. Please try to check/repair it. Please follow this Microsoft KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/272227/